# I can´t change innodb_buffer_pool_instances

Tags: innodb, buffer-pool, instance

I recently updated my mariadb database to 10.5.5 and I can't set innodb_buffer_pool_instances

```
innodb_log_file_size = 3G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
```

But when

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%innodb_buffer_pool_%";
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 12884901888    |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Do I need other vars to configure pool instances? Which?

Thank you very much for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[innodb_buffer_pool_instances](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15058) where removed in 10.5 because they offered no benefit due to internal restructuring of the code.

There is no replacement setting.

The variable, that serves no purpose, is there for compatibility only and will be removed in 10.6